# Executing code before a controller's method is invoked?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to make an action filter or something that runs **before** the action method itself runs on the controller?

I need this to analyze a few values in the request before the action runs.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can override OnActionExecuting method in controller class

```
protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
//Your logic is here...
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1337907/how-to-wire-common-code-from-a-base-controller-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: And what if I need to do it for all my controllers at once with a single code fragment?

Comment: Create a base class for all your controllers, as it's described in Artem's comment

Comment: You can use AOP (e.g. PostSharp or similar).

Comment: @Mathias Also you can hook up to the `Application_*` event handlers in global.asax.

Answer (score 5):

You could use an attribute:

```
public class MyFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        // Your logic here...

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

And if you want to apply it to all controllers, in your Global.asax.cs:

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    filters.Add(new MyFilterAttribute());
}

protected void Application_Start()
{
    // Other code removed for clarity of this example...

    RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

    // Other code removed for clarity of this example...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If u don't want to use a base controller u can also add a own HttpHandler and register it in the web.config. In the BeginProcessRequest method u can analyse the values.