# Asp.net MVC Page titles in database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

Has anyone here structured your views, controller and actions in such a way that the page titles are set from the database. How do you identify one view from another ? In which phase of the lifecycle do you retrieve the page title and set it for the view/action method
a lot of posts are scattered for asp.net, php but then a efficient way for mvc I am yet to find

Comment: well, if you set on controller the `ViewBag.Title = "String comes from Database"` que do not set on View, it will work fine.

Comment: @FelipeOriani that would be lame wouldn't it? doing this in every controller action method god no i would go in maintenance nightmare then

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use action filters:

```
public class ControllerAndActionNameAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{        
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.Controller.ViewBag.ControllerName = filterContext.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
        filterContext.Controller.ViewBag.ActionName = filterContext.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    } 
}
```

But instead of putting the action- or controllername into the viewbag, you could load stuff from your database based on action and/or controller.

Comment: awesome i was just going through a article to do that.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9462761/executing-code-before-a-controllers-method-is-invoked

Answer (score 1):

What if you have service or helper method that retrieves all the titles from the database and stores them to some sort of cache or static variable think `Dictionary`.  Depending on how you plan to update with the site running determines when or how.

Then expose a static helper method that the views can call to retrieve their title.

You could probably even incorporate a T4 template to set a property for each view to call the method with the correct retrieval key

Comment: What's unique about each view that i can use to retrieve the page titles? Is there a method that executes before a controller action executes so that i can hook there get the title for Controller & ActionMethod finally setting it in the viewbag